# Find value of scrabble word

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I have little experience in any higher level language. Fiddled with basic and dos-batch when I was a kid.

I'm trying to find the point value of a word in scrabble. This kind of recursive structure seems slow and inefficient. What would be a better way to address this problem in terms of program structure/concept?

```
value_list = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 
              'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 
              'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 
              'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10}

word_index = 0
total = 0

def find_value(word):
     global word_index
     global total
     x = word[word_index]
     total = total + value_list[x]
     if len(word) > word_index + 1:
         word_index = word_index + 1
         find_value(word)
```

Comment: I removed the `dict()` call, it was entirely redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd loop over `word` directly and use `sum()`:

```
def find_value(word):
    return sum(value_list[char] for char in word)
```

There is no need to use recursion here; the above needs no globals either. Try to avoid global state, as that easily leads to hard-to-debug problems when you start using functions in multiple locations.

Comment: Christ, that was fast. Thanks, I see how that is far superior.

Comment: A bit off topic; Can you present an example of when recursion is preferable to drawing values in this manner? Given you can make statements like this, it seems completely unnecessary, and quite a bit of overhead. I only ask because the exercise I was given was to solve this problem in this manner and it seemed cumbersome to me.

Comment: Recursion is useful when you have a problem that is most easily solved by a divide-and-conquer approach; split up the work in smaller bits and apply the same function to those bits, until you have bits small enough to make the answer almost self-evident.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can use `list` of values instead of `dict`, and just count index for the letter `x` in this `list` as `ord(x) - ord('a')`

Second, don't use `global`, it is a bad programming habit. You should accumulate your value in local variable and then `return` this value from the function.

And third, use loop instead of recursion or, even better, functions like `sum`.

Comment: I can see how using global would become confusing in a larger program. Is there another reason it should be avoided, or just for simplicity?

Comment: The dictionary is actually easier here, as a list would require you to convert each character to an integer index first. The `ord(x) - ord('a')` costs more than the dictionary hash calculation (in pure C).

Answer (score 0):

`def find_value(word):`

```
    return sum(map(lambda x:value_list[x], list(word)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, function call is expensive is Python.

Martijn Pieters's method is a good example for beginners to understand [list-comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

If you want a more simple and readable way, try this:

```
sum(value_list.values())
```

Comment: This doesn't sum a specific word, only all the scrabble costs of all the tiles.