# How to check the highest value of word in txt file using letter_score as in code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to count the value of words from imported txt file in Python? I did sth like this and have no idea what can I do to count the value of words.

```
import itertools


letter_score = 
{

                'a' : 1, 'e' : 1, 'o' : 1,
               'i' : 1, 'n' : 1, 'r' : 1,
               'l' : 1, 't' : 1, 'l' : 1,
               's' : 1, 'n' : 1, 'd' : 2,
               'g' : 2, 'b' : 3, 'c' : 3,
               'm' : 3, 'p' : 3, 'f' : 4,
               'h' : 4, 'v' : 4, 'w' : 4,
               'y' : 4, 'k' : 5, 'j' : 8,
               'x' : 8, 'q' : 10, 'z' : 10 
}




def load_dict(path):
    words = "dictionary.txt"
    return words


fname = input('dictionary.txt')
num_words = 0

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in 'f':
        words = line.split()
        num_words += len(words)
print("Number of words:")
print(num_words)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find value of scrabble word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223922/find-value-of-scrabble-word)

Comment: `for line in 'f':` ? And `fname = input('dictionary.txt')` - are you reading from user?

Comment: @Austin I have created two files in PyCharm. One is a simple txt file and second one is .py file with the code. I have to take words from txt file and return the word with the highest value according to the letter_score that is above.

Comment: @FredLarson I saw this post but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @paweljvn: Then I'm not sure what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like list() it create a list of characters and using something like a for to iterate the list and compare values with your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Define function which calculate word's values, create list of all words, apply function and then find max. value:

```
def word_value(word, dic):
    """calculate value of the word"""
    return sum([dic[char] for char in word])


def read_file(fname):
    num_words = 0
    all_words = []
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in 'f':
            words = line.split()
            num_words += len(words)
            all_words.extend(words)
    return all_words, num_words

fname = input('dictionary.txt')
all_words, num_words = read_file(fname)

letter_score = {
            'a' : 1, 'e' : 1, 'o' : 1,
           'i' : 1, 'n' : 1, 'r' : 1,
           'l' : 1, 't' : 1, 'l' : 1,
           's' : 1, 'n' : 1, 'd' : 2,
           'g' : 2, 'b' : 3, 'c' : 3,
           'm' : 3, 'p' : 3, 'f' : 4,
           'h' : 4, 'v' : 4, 'w' : 4,
           'y' : 4, 'k' : 5, 'j' : 8,
           'x' : 8, 'q' : 10, 'z' : 10 }

all_words_values = [(word, word_value(word, letter_score)) for word in all_words]
# list of tuples [(word, value)]
max_word = max(all_words_values, key=lambda x: x[1])  # find maximum by value 
# max_word is smth like ("apple", 9)
```

Hope it helps!